# How do I set a JSON header in Slim 3 framework (PHP)?

Tags: php, json, slim

How do I set a JSON header in Slim 3?

```
$app->get('/joinable', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    return getJoinable(); // Returns JSON_encoded data
});
```

I have tried the following

`$response = $app->response();
$response['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';`
`$app->contentType('application/json');`

Comment: I think you have to add some details, man...

Answer (score 6):

Never used Slim framework, but according to [their documentation](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/objects/response.html#the-response-headers), it should be something in the lines of:

```
$app->get('/joinable', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    $body = $response->getBody();
    $body->write('{"your_content": "here"}');

    return $response->withHeader(
        'Content-Type',
        'application/json'
    )->withBody($body);
});
```

What you are trying with `header('Content-Type: application/json');` may actually work, but since you are using a framework for your application, you should respect their guidelines, or you'll end up with lots of problems. Also, that `getJoinable()` is a global call, you should really learn some OOP and, more than that, follow the [PSR](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/) guidelines, because Slim 3 is built using those guidelines.

Comment: Okay, I tried this and it worked, thanks. But a new issue appeared: the response is being cut short, resulting in missing data and invalid JSON.

Answer (score 5):

You can simply do the following (note I am using the built in json encoder helper):

```
return $response->withJson($dataArray)->withHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
```

if you are returning a lot of JSON, you might consider creating a route group:

```
$app->group('/api', function () {
   $this->response->withHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
   $this->get(...);
   $this->get(...);
}
```

It's a time saver and keeps your code clean scaleable and  maintainable.

Answer (score 3):

The request object has a method to convert an array to JSON and set the header at the same time. [See documentation here](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/objects/response.html#returning-json)

```
$app->get('/joinable', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    return $response->withJson(getJoinable());
});
```

Except that `getJoinable()` needs to return an Array, because `withJson()` will convert it to json for you.

---

Now, if you insist on setting the header yourself, [see the documentation here](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/objects/response.html#the-response-headers)

The code would look like this

```
$app->get('/joinable', function ($request, $response, $args) {

    $body = $this->getBody();
    $body->rewind(); // ensure your JSON is the only thing in the body
    $body->write(getJoinable());

    return $response->withHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=utf-8');
});
```

---

If you're sure the body is empty at this point, you can save a step and just use the `write()` method in the `Response` object.

```
$app->get('/joinable', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    $response->write(getJoinable());
    $response = $response->withHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=utf-8');
    return $response;
});
```

---

And even shorter notation

```
$app->get('/joinable', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    return $response->write(getJoinable())
        ->withHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=utf-8');
});
```

With PHP 5.4+ you may also want to a json pretty printing (not suggested for larger payloads, as it adds around 10-25% more to your transferred bytesize):

```
$app->get('/joinable', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    return $response->write(json_encode(getJoinable(), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT))
        ->withHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=utf-8');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I would advice a total abstraction of the renderer. One that would be easier to maintain at the long run.
You could have a Renderer class with this method for instance:

```
public function render(Response $response, array $data, $status_code)
{
    return $response->withStatus((int) $status_code)
        ->withHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=utf-8')
        ->withJson($data);
}
```

where `$response` is an instance of `Slim\Http\Response`.

You can find a more robust Renderer class here: [slim3-api-output-format](https://github.com/akrabat/slim3-api-output-format/blob/master/app/src/Renderer.php)

Hope this helps someone else.